# Running webdriverIO in with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, webdriver-io

Im struggling to understand how to properly configure my compose file to run webdriverio.

I am following instructions:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Docker-Compose

and here

https://github.com/blueimp/wdio/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

I am mainly struggling to understand what hubs should i have and what depends on what. Any input is welcome

here is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
    chromedriver:
        image: blueimp/chromedriver
        environment:
            - DISABLE_X11=false
            - ENABLE_VNC=true
            - EXPOSE_X11=true
        ports:
            - 127.0.0.1:7900:7900
    geckodriver:
        image: blueimp/geckodriver
        environment:
            - DISABLE_X11=false
            - ENABLE_VNC=true
            - EXPOSE_X11=true
        ports:
            - 127.0.0.1:6901:6900
    selenium:
        image: selenium/hub
        ports:
            - '14444:4444'
    firefox:
        image: selenium/node-firefox
        ports:
            - 5900
        environment:
            - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium
        depends_on:
            - selenium
    chrome:
        image: selenium/node-chrome
        ports:
            - 5900
        environment:
            - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium
        depends_on:
            - selenium
    my-app-selenium:
        build: .
        environment:
            SELENIUM_REMOTE_URL: 'http://selenium:4444/wd/hub'
            SELENIUM_APP_SUPER_URL: 'http://192.168.0.10:9000/super/'
            SELENIUM_APP_ADMIN_URL: 'http://192.168.0.10:9000/admin/'
```

here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:carbon

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
WORKDIR /var/app/current
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && \
  apt-get install -y ant && \
  apt-get clean;

# Fix certificate issues
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install ca-certificates-java && \
  apt-get clean && \
  update-ca-certificates -f;

# Setup JAVA_HOME -- useful for docker commandline
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME

COPY . .

CMD ./wait && npm run test
```

last error I got in console was

```
unknown error: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600233 (523efee95e3d68b8719b3a1c83051aa63aa6b10d),platform=Linux 4.15.0-46-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

and

```
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

wdio.conf.js

```
//to use debug option run `DEBUG=true followed by your .conf.js`
const defaultTimeoutInterval = process.env.DEBUG ? (60 * 60 * 500) : 90000;

exports.config = {
    hostname: 'selenium',
    port: 4444,
    specs: [
        './test/specs/*.js'
    ],
    exclude: [],
    maxInstances: 15,
    capabilities: [{
        maxInstances: 5,
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }, ],
    sync: false,
    logLevel: 'silent',
    deprecationWarnings: true,
    bail: 0,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9000',
    waitforTimeout: 10000,
    connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    // services: ['docker'],
    framework: 'mocha',
    mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 90000,
        compilers: ['js:@babel/register'],
    },
    reporters: [
        'spec',
        ['junit', {
            outputDir: './test/reports/junit-results/',
            outputFileFormat: function (opts) { // optional
                return `results-${opts.cid}.${opts.capabilities}.xml`
            }
        }],

        ['allure', {
            outputDir: './test/reports/allure-results/',
            disableWebdriverStepsReporting: true,
            disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: false,
        }],
    ],
    onPrepare: function (config, capabilities) {
        console.log('**** let\'s go ****');
    },
    beforeSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
        require('@babel/register');
    },
    before: function (capabilities, specs) {
        /**
         * Setup the Chai assertion framework
         */
        const chai = require('chai');
        global.expect = chai.expect;
        global.assert = chai.assert;
        global.should = chai.should();
    },
    afterTest: function (test) {
        //console.log(test);
    },
    onComplete: function (exitCode) {
        console.log('**** that\'s it ****');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is going on when you get that error? Is it when you are building the image from that Dockerfile? Or is it when you are starting up the stack? I guess it is on the last step of building the image - on the command: `npm run test`

Comment: all the images build and begin to run but after a few seconds selenium runs and crashes with those 2 errors above

Comment: Is it the `selenium` container that is giving the error? Or is it `my-app-selenium`. The reason here is, that the Chrome executable is not on the path - in the container that is trying to invoke it.

Comment: `my-app-selenium` is where the error occurs. what do you mean by not on the path?

Comment: Are you using karma for the tests? And are you using puppeteer for the API control of chrome? If so, can you show/link your `karma.conf.js`?

Comment: I'm using mocha. I've added my wdio.conf.js file. I am not using puppeteer

Comment: I'm guess mocha is trying to execute your chrome test on the selenium/hub - and not the selenium/node-chrome. Can you access: http://localhost:4444/grid/console and see if the selenium/chrome node has been registered?

Comment: You can also try setting this in the config: `directConnect: false`

Comment: can't seem to access localhost:4444 at all when the application runs. you did mention above that I need to provide a path for chromedriver which I think makes sense since it cannot be found in the running container. `environment: -PATH_ADD=/var/app/current` - is this what u mean?

Comment: Sorry! I now see that you are mapping the selenium hub out to 14444, try http://localhost:14444/grid/console. Well, there are some solutions when you are running the tests locally that set the path of the chrome binary - but I do not think this is the solution here. The selenium/node-chrome image is specialized for the tests that you want to run - it surely has the chrome binary already. The issue is with making the hub realize that you want to use chrome for the tests, and not use the hub itself for running the tests. At least, this is what I think.

Comment: ah yes 14444 lol. I can access that now during runtime and see the config but still getting the same errors. Even after removing geckodriver and chromedriver from my docker-compose file, the issue still persists.

Comment: Could you fix this? I'm going insane trying to setup a working fully containerized webdriverio testing env